# Equivalent of ".gitignore" file with Subversion

Tags: svn

I am being forced to work with Subversion on a current project.

Someone has unkindly added the `bin` and `obj` folders to the repository.

Other than removing them, and committing the removal, is there an equivalent of .gitignore file I can add to the repository to make the guilty party in the development team never add them again?

I know I can alter my own global ignore pattern, but ideally I'd like the whole development team to be able to share this on a project level.

Comment: lolxxx... `I am being forced to work with Subversion on a current project`. same here even in 2018

Comment: Hehe: still in 2023 on my side.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is done by a svn:ignore property in SVN. This property can be added to a folder.
Let us imagine the following:

```
 +-- root
       +-- bin
       +-- ...
```

to ignore the bin folder you have to set the svn:ignore property onto the root folder. First change into the root folder and do the following on command line:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "bin" .
```

Or you can do this via TortoiseSVN on Windows (file->properties->Subversion Tab).. Further reading in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html).

Comment: Maybe most won't be as unobservant as me, but if it's failing with an error like "explicit target required" you're probably missing the `.` at the end of the command like I did...

Answer (score 15):

I have just started with Android Studio and I ended up editing the svn:ignore property in the GUI. I used the Edit Properties in the Subversion menu and added a whole bunch of ignores which were mentioned in other posts.

[image]

Below is  what I ignored and Android Studio marked these visually with different colour after I edited the property.

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin
gen
gradle

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
out
build
production
*.iml
*.iws
*.ipr
*~
*.swp
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
svn propset svn:ignore 'file you want to ignore'
```

See *[Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html)*.

Also check out [the global-ignores configuration option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2).

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with TortoiseSVN, this can be accomplished by:

- Right click bin directory -> TortoiseSVN -> add to ignore list -> bin

When you commit, your root or trunk directory will be highlighted. You can also ignore multiple files at the same time by selecting them then

- Right click -> TortoiseSVN -> add to ignore list -> ignore *X* items by name.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to hide status items instead of use `svn:ignore`. To do it I've created a `.svnignore` file with patterns that I want to ignore and this alias:

```
alias svn-status='svn st * 2>&1 | grep -v "$(cat .svnignore)"'
```

Comment: Linux/Bash I presume?

Comment: How does this prevent adding e.g. a folder named `bin`?