# what files to save to repository laravel - framework workflow

Tags: php, svn, laravel, laravel-4

Let me just say this, I'm very new to composer and laravel.

I'm a long time cli fan, so I feel very comfy with composer. I've used npm, ruby gems etc, I see all the benefits to package managers.

Problem is, I'm saving entire laravel dir to my svn repository. It seems kinda redundant, especially vendor/bootstrap dirs.

I also find it uncomfortable to have vendor packages same in every laravel app directory on the same server, I'm kinda missing global gems thing from ruby.

How do you deal with this? Is it possible to have laravel like a shared library on server and then just have app/public directories in each project?

What files should be saved to repository? can composer handle all the dependency installation on production server? I see laravel files come with .gitignore files, where do I get svn version?

Much confusion atm in my head, hope to clear these up, so I can start actually writing code ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First off, as far as I know, it is not easily possible to install laravel and it's dependencies globally. I wouldn't worry about that too much though since composer will cache them so it won't need to download everything for each project you set up.

### Vendor directory

The `vendor` dir should definitely NOT be in your repository. I'm no SVN expert but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293595/1903366) you can ignore directories by doing:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "vendor" .
```

Most SVN client software should have a similar function in a context menu or similar.

### Deploy workflow

Ideally you checkout the repo on your production server and then run `composer update` to install all dependencies. If you don't have terminal access or have other troubles with that I recommend you download a fresh copy of your repo and run `composer udpate`. Then upload it to your server.