# Flutter, which folder not to commit to svn

Tags: flutter

Do android and ios folder need to commit to svn?

I believe /build .packages are not to be committed.

I haven't found detailed docs on this topic. I only find this https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/private-files

I'm aware there is .gitignore file but I think this file is ignored because I'm using TortoiseSVN. Every time I commit I got like 200+ files committed. And may affect other users when they do update.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do android and ios folder need to commit to svn?

**Yes**, always comit these folders to svn(but you can skip some auto generated files)

There are three main folders in the Flutter project:
 `lib`, `android` and `ios`.

`lib` takes care of your Dart files. The **Android and iOS** folders exist to actually build an app on those respective platforms with the Dart files running on them. They also help you add permissions and platform-specific functionality to your project. When you run a Flutter project, it builds depending on which emulator or device it is running on, doing a Gradle or XCode build using the folders inside it.

**In short, those folders are entire apps which set the stage for the Flutter code to run.**

Don’t commit the following files and directories:

```
# See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/private-files.html

# Files and directories created by pub
.packages
.pub/
build/
# If you're building an application, you may want to check-in your pubspec.lock
pubspec.lock

# Directory created by dartdoc
# If you don't generate documentation locally you can remove this line.
doc/api/
```

From `flutter create`:

```
.DS_Store
.atom/
.idea
.packages
.pub/
build/
ios/.generated/
packages
pubspec.lock
.flutter-plugins
```

For more information please refer [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13892#issuecomment-424537206) to check which files are auto generated.

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 4):

If you create a Flutter project it contains 3 `.gitignore` files.
One in the project root and one in each `ios/` and `android/`.
These files already cover most cases.

**update**

They unified these 3 `.gitignore` into a single one

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

Comment: I only have 1 .gitignore on the root....And because I'm using svn I think this file is "ignored" too :)

Comment: The last time I checked they were 3 but I remember seeing discussions that they should be merged and in a newly created project there is now only 1 such file. I updated my answer.

Comment: Can I use svn to take this .gitignore file?

Comment: There seems to be something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293539/equivalent-of-gitignore-file-with-subversion. You would need to convert it yourself

Comment: what about ios/build/ folder, ios/Podfile and ios/Podfile.lock file?

Comment: Lockfiles for application projects depends on your preferences. For published packages you usually should not commit them. Otherwise check https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/.gitignore That file is kept updated.