# Why flutter project file take so much space in drive?

Tags: flutter

I am new in android as well as flutter. After creating a flutter project in android studio I run the project. Then I show that the flutter project file take 651 MB as shown in the picture [Project File Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYWCE.png)

My question is why it take so much space is it possible to reduce it. If so then please tell me how.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. A flutter project size should be irrelevant as the important thing is to reduce the output apk file sizes. Any android project will also reach that size also android studio will eat up all the RAM that's normal so we can do nothing about it.

Comment: upto ~1.5 gb its normal, if you still want calm your anxiety run `flutter clean`

Comment: A newly created flutter project was `316KB` in my system. And after I built the apk it became 200MB. I did a flutter clean and it became 1MB again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the libraries downloaded for compiling iOS/Android builds. You can just commit needed files (skipping auto-generated files) and just download the dependencies when setting up the project on a different machine.

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53515001/2497859) for the required files on a Flutter project.